# Email/Newsletter not taking css classes

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I am checking emailer on [Putsmail](https://putsmail.com/tests/new).
When first time I put HTML emailer code into [Putsmail](https://putsmail.com/tests/new) for testing it's giving proper result. All the CSS are into  tag, But when I add some extra CSS classes to that style tag, and upload that HTML code into [Putsmail](https://putsmail.com/tests/new), the output emailer not taking that extra classes when I inspect that output mail into Gmail.

Note: For some reasons, I have to write all CSS code into the head  tag.

Comment: The `<head>` tag is removed by the mail client (e.g. gmail) very often. 
So there won't be any styles. I recommend you to put a `<style>` tag in the body or even use inline-styles only.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: Outlook ignores some tags in the `<head>` It also ignores some tags in inline-styles. Please post your html code so we can tell you the issues you are having.